# What is the SQLite query to replace a string of characters with another string that includes a line break?

Tags: sqlite

I'd like to replace **); "** in column "Note" with **)Carriage Return"**, but with the condition that "Phrase" column (BOOL) is set as TRUE. I tried using the following query but that didn't work:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM "Slovník";
UPDATE Slovník
WHERE   Phrase = 1
SET Note = replace(Note, '); "', ')CHAR(13)"');
```

In other words, I'd like to replace a semicolon with a line break in the column Note in my database under the above conditions:
[screenshot][1]

To avoid the semicolon being replaced somewhere else, (somewhere other than between the sentence examples), I have to include the extra characters, such as **); "**

(Please let me know if my question isn't clear enough and I'll try to clarify.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the concatenation operator `||` with the function `CHAR()` and don't wrap the function inside the single quotes:

```
UPDATE [Slovník]
SET Note = replace(Note, '); "', ')' || CHAR(13) || '"')
WHERE   Phrase = 1
```

It's better to use this `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE   Phrase = 1 AND Note LIKE '%); "%'
```

to avoid unnecessary updates for the rows that do not contain `'); "'`.

Comment: Thank you for you reply, unfortunately that didn't work for me either. I get a syntax error.